# Retrieve value from ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I need to retrieve some value from my ListView, which is bound with SQL to Order by Price ASC

**Requirement :**

1. Counts of total rows in the list
2. Minimum Price and Seller Name, who has minimum price in the list
3. Maximum Price and Seller Name, who has maximum price in the list

   ```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
             <td><asp:Label ID="SellersName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SellerName") %>'/></td>
             <td><asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price","₹ {0:N2}") %>'/>     </td>
          </tr>                               
       </ItemTemplate>                        
   </asp:ListView>
   ```

How can it retrieve this information in C#? Is this possible using itembound or anything else

Comment: for point 1 you can use listView.Items.Count (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.items.aspx)

Comment: OK, **ListView1.Items.Count** to retrieve counts of total rows in the list

Comment: for point 2 and 3, you have the collection **Items**, you can use LINQ  to cycle and find specific value you want (minPrice, or maxPrice), and depending on it's position in that collection take the Seller Name also

Comment: I have Tried ItemDatabound. But that is giving me all rows. While i need the count, minprice, maxprice.

Comment: ListView1.Items.Count  is returning "0". While there is 8 rows in listview..Not sure what is the wrong with that

Comment: Meorfi. Can you please share the code??

Comment: use this example http://aspalliance.com/1542_Data_Manipulation_using_ListView_Server_Control_with_ASPNET_35.all#Page5

Comment: Meorfi..aspalliance example not explaining my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of Listview on browser.
    
    SellerName  Price
    AB  1980.00
    XX  2000.00
    YY  2100.00
    ZZ  2300.00